# ASP.NET 3.5 Page character encoding problem

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a problem in my asp.net 3.5 application (C#) when I try to render in my pages characters like 'è' which are shown in a very strange manner (if i'm lucky i get a ? mark in my web page). in fact Expression Web, when i open my web site, substitutes the è char with �...
How can I tell asp.net that I want to use a particular charset so that i can write in the html source letters like è without using hexadecimal codes??????

I tried in the web.config this:

inside the  system.web namespace of the file but nothing works....
Can anyone tell me how to do? THANKS in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK I inserted in every page the  element so that everything is ok...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `Server.HTMLEn`